# Plotting markers using leaflet and rCharts from a data frame with lat and lon values

Tags: r, gis, leaflet, rcharts

I am trying to learn the Leaflet functionality with rCharts and would like to plot multiple markers and popups garnered from a `data.frame` object in `R`

```
df <- data.frame(location = c("White House", "Impound Lot", "Bush Garden", "Rayburn", "Robertson House", "Beers Elementary"), latitude = c(38.89710, 38.81289, 38.94178, 38.8867787, 38.9053894, 38.86466), longitude = c(-77.036545, -77.0171983, -77.073311, -77.0105317, -77.0616441, -76.95554))
df
          location latitude longitude
1      White House 38.89710 -77.03655
2      Impound Lot 38.81289 -77.01720
3      Bush Garden 38.94178 -77.07331
4          Rayburn 38.88678 -77.01053
5  Robertson House 38.90539 -77.06164
6 Beers Elementary 38.86466 -76.95554
```

I tried modifying the code from the example on [Ramnanth's rCharts page](http://ramnathv.github.io/rCharts/). This is my modification:

```
map <- Leaflet$new()
map$setView(c(38.89710, -77.03655), 12)
map$tileLayer(provider = 'Stamen.TonerLite')
map$marker(c(df$latitude, df$longitude), bindPopup = df$location)
```

This code does not produce any markers. I am looking for a solution whereby I can plot the lat and lon for each observation and have a marker with a popup populated by the value in the location column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That won't work because df$latitude returns a vector with all the latitudes from your dataframe:

```
df$latitude
## [1] 38.89710 38.81289 38.94178 38.88678 38.90539 38.86466
df$longitude
##b[1] -77.03655 -77.01720 -77.07331 -77.01053 -77.06164 -76.95554
```

You'll need to add you markers in a loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    map$marker(c(df[i, "latitude"], df[i, "longitude"]), bindPopup = df[i, "location"])
}
```

Note: did this quickly, freehand, just starting out with R and am unable to test this at the moment.

Comment: Just to clarify if another newbie this, I am adding @iH8's code in place of the `map$marker` line in my original post.